# Advanced PHP image sharing. From a DB to Facebook wall?

Tags: php, database, facebook, image

I'm trying to integrate facebook share by using images directly from my database.

Static images using the OG tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://X.com/image.jpg" />"
```

Works fine.

However, my images are not static, they are being called from my database using this:

```
echo "<img src=\"pic.php?id=".$id."\"/>";
```

Where pictures render fine on my website but facebook share does not pick them up.

The logical thing in my mind then would be to do this:

```
echo "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"http://X.com/pic.php?id=".$id."\"/>";
```

Sadly, this does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a URL rewrite to create a friendly URL, e.g.

```
http://x.com/pic/id
```

If you are using Apache, that would be a `.htaccess` file (assuming you have `mod_rewrite` enabled), something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^pic/([^/\.]+)/?$ /pic.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried your solution:

     http://x.com/pic/id

Which displays the correct images.

However, changing:

    echo "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"http://X.com/pic.php?id=".$id."\"/>";

To:

    echo "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"http://X.com/pic/".$id."\"/>";

Doesnt help facebook scrape the image.

Using the debugging tool, facebook does not have any problems with the orginal URL or rewrite.

    Meta Tag: <meta property="og:image "content="http://X.com/pic/123" />

Comment: I am still looking for a solution that will scrape images from DB calls.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me using asp
Image is retrieved from MySQL blob field by asp script.
the debugger shows the image and gives no error but the button on the page doesn't take the image.
And it should have nothing todo with caching as it is a brand new page.

Page: http://www.ffkama.be/html/2_agenda_detail.asp?ps=id51

Image URL: http://www.ffkama.be/root/imager_ag.asp?id=51

UPDATE: I forgot the code in the HEAD TAG :( One thing is sure, without the 'prefix="og: h t tp://ogp.me/ns# fb: ht tp://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: h t tp://ogp.me/ns/website#"' in the HEAD Tag, the debugger doesn't give an arror and the image shows up in the dubugger but the image won't show up on your page. Then the page is cached and there are only 2 solutions: 1. rename the page 2. wait several days for the cache to expire

Comment: you don't need to wait several days. Just use facebook debugger tool to see what facebook is seeing on your page:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/